# R - RSelenium - getPageSource

Tags: r, rselenium

## Rselenium - R

I'm using RSelenium and rvest to scrape wattpad.com by category.

For do that i need to make some scrolls. All works properly but when i want to load page source i'm get an strange error message.

My code is as follows:

where gat is a vector of URLs

```r
for(i in gat){
  
  print(i)
  
  if(grepl("user", i)==FALSE){
    cat_url2 <- paste0("https://www.wattpad.com",i,"/new",sep="")
    remDr$navigate(cat_url2)
    Sys.sleep(2)
    
    
    k <- 1:3
    
    for(l in k){
      Sys.sleep(4)
      print(l)
      remDr$executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    }
    
    Sys.sleep(4)
    peich <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% read_html()

    Sys.sleep(2)
    
    title <- peich %>% html_nodes(".browse-story-item") %>% html_nodes(".content") %>% html_nodes(".title") %>% html_text2()
    hrefs <- peich %>% html_nodes(".browse-story-item") %>% html_nodes(".content") %>% html_nodes(".title") %>% html_attrs() %>% map(3) %>% unlist()
    username <- peich %>% html_nodes(".browse-story-item") %>% html_nodes(".content") %>% html_nodes(".username") %>% html_text2()
    href_user <- peich %>% html_nodes(".browse-story-item") %>% html_nodes(".content") %>% html_nodes(".username") %>% html_attrs() %>% map(2) %>% unlist()
    read <- peich %>% html_nodes(".browse-story-item") %>% html_nodes(".content") %>% html_nodes(".social-meta") %>% html_nodes(".read-count") %>% html_text2()
    vote <- peich %>% html_nodes(".browse-story-item") %>% html_nodes(".content") %>% html_nodes(".social-meta") %>% html_nodes(".vote-count") %>% html_text2()
    parts <- peich %>% html_nodes(".browse-story-item") %>% html_nodes(".content") %>% html_nodes(".social-meta") %>% html_nodes(".part-count") %>% html_text2() 
    desc <- peich %>% html_nodes(".browse-story-item") %>% html_nodes(".content") %>% html_nodes(".description") %>% html_text2() 
    
    Sys.sleep(2)
    
    categorias_fin<- data.frame(title,hrefs,username,href_user,read,vote,parts,desc) 
    Sys.sleep(1)
    
    
    if(nrow(categorias_fin)>0){
      categorias_fin$categoria <- i
      Sys.sleep(1)
      categorias_fin2 <- rbind(categorias_fin2,categorias_fin)
    }
    
    rm(categorias_fin)
  }
}
```

The error is as follows:
[eError returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lkzob.png)

I've open server with different versions and always get same result.

How can i solve this issue?